# how do I list EBS volumes with Name tag's value?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am currently executing below AWS cli command

```
 aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[*].[VolumeId,AvailabilityZone,InstanceId,State,VolumeType,Attachments[0].InstanceId]'
```

I get output as

[image]

I also wanted to include Name of the volume(the value associated with Name tag) in the generated output. What addition can I do to the CLI command to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the following additional as optional parameters:

- attachment.device - The device name specified in the block device mapping (for example, /dev/sda1 ).
- tag :key- The key/value combination of a tag assigned to the resource. Use the tag key in the filter name and the tag value as the filter value. For example, to find all resources that have a tag with the key Owner and the value TeamA , specify tag:Owner for the filter name and TeamA for the filter value.
- tag-key - The key of a tag assigned to the resource. Use this filter to find all resources assigned a tag with a specific key, regardless of the tag value.

Comment: I am bit new to CLI can you please modify the command I am unable to get the desired results

Comment: aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId,InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId,AZ:AvailabilityZone,Size:Size,TAG:Tags,BlockDevice:attachment.device}" --output table

Comment: Njoi thats great. Can you please mark the answer as correct so that it can be tracked. Thank You

Comment: If you want just the Name tag, you can run this command: `aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId,InstanceId:Attachments[0].InstanceId,AZ:AvailabilityZone,Size:Size,Name:Tags[?Key==\`Name\`].Value | [0],BlockDevice:attachment.device}" --output table`

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using Boto3 and Python:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session(profile_name="aws_account_a")
client = session.client('ec2', region_name="eu-west-2")

response = client.describe_volumes().get('Volumes', [])

for volume in response:
    for v in volume['Attachments']:
        print(volume['VolumeId'], volume['AvailabilityZone'], volume['State'], v['InstanceId'], volume['VolumeType'])
```